# Page layout in Root site with lookup field that refers a list in child variations sites Issue in sandboxed solution sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, page-layout, variations, no-code-solution

I have a  sharepoint online site created with No Code Sandboxed Solution.
In the feature scope site , i put the content type that contains the lookup field "Category" and the module of the Page layouts. In the feature scope web, i put the list "Categories" refered by the lookup field because i want that every child variation site contains its list "Categories" with its language
For testing , after uploading my wsp , i created  my first  variation child site ,then i activated the feature scoped web .
The issue is that when i try to create in my varition site ,a page basing on page layout with lookup field that refers to list "Catgories " created in my child variation site , the lookup field appears empty!!
So what should i do ? help please!!

Comment: Could you please explain more the problem.
Thank you